# Typescript: declare ReturnType for all functions in a file (how to create a redux action type)

Tags: typescript, redux

I would like to create a `ReturnType` for all functions in a file.

For example, for redux actions file:

```
// files.actions.ts

export const setFiles = (files: IFile[]) => ({
    type: FILES_ACTION_TYPE.SET_FILES,
    payload: files,
});

export const clearFiles = () => ({
    type: FILES_ACTION_TYPE.CLEAR_FILES,
    payload: undefined
});

export type FilesAction = ReturnType<typeof clearFiles | typeof setFiles>
```

Is there an elegant way to have types of all the functions without writing each of them by hand?

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question:

We would specifically recommend *not* writing action creators by hand.  Instead, you should use [the `createSlice` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) from [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), as it automatically generates action creators for you.  It's also already written in TS, and ensures that the action creators are correctly typed to match the reducers.

Related to that, I personally see no real benefit to attempting to define a union type of all actions that can be dispatched, or limiting the set of actions that can be passed to `dispatch`.

Comment: Due to this answer I struggled for hours implementing redux toolkit in my Angular app. I couldn't find any docs or tutorials for that, for example integration with NgRedux. Eventually I achieved the goal. About defining a union type of all actions - NgRedux dispatch expects AnyAction type, I thought it would be the solution.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah, most Redux users are using React as the UI layer, so that's my default working assumption.  The Redux core team also don't maintain NgRedux, so we don't currently have any info on using it in our docs. I _would_ like to add a "UI Layer Integration" section to the Redux docs with info on working with other UI layers as well, but not sure when that will happen.